# Defining an API caller class with ASP.NET Core

Tags: api, asp.net-core, prestashop

I'm developing an App that makes calls to the Prestashop API. I've worked with APIs before but not in ASP.NET Core.

On the client side in Java (retrofit) we used to have an interface where we defined our URL calls and function names like so:

```java
public interface TodoApi {

    @POST("/owners/login")
    Call<String> loginP(@Body UserLogin login);

    @POST("/workers/login")
    Call<String> loginT(@Body UserLogin login);

    @POST("/workers/token")
    Call<String> tokenT(@Body String token);

    @POST("/owners/token")
    Call<String> tokenP(@Body String token);

    ...
}
```

Is there a standard (or a way) of achieving this in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: What does this have to do with the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Comment: What is your expected standard way? How did you achieve your requirement with apis? Do you mean you want asp.net core api to return xml? What is your expected input and output for asp.net core api?

Comment: The return value isn't important sorry if i didn't make myself clear. I was asking if there's a standard or a "good practice" way for defining the api calls like there is in retrofit (like specifying the api URL like `/owners/login` in the code above) or I just make a bunch of functions with HTTP requests inside for every api call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "standard" way of doing it, but there is a port of `retrofit` that is called `refit` that you can use.

There are multiple other ways, like e.g. using `HttpClient` directly, using `RestSharp`, etc.

You can read more on how to perform http requests on Microsoft docs e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0).